# Is $x$ rational? If so, express $x$ as a ratio of two integers. If not, give a counterexample.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose $a,b,c$ are all integers and $x,y,x$ are all real numbers (non-zero), satisfy the relations.

\begin{align*}\frac{xy}{x+y} &= a ,& \frac{xz}{x+z} &= b, &\frac{yz}{y+z} &= c.\end{align*}

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} =\frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: My first attempt would be to rearrange for the variables (note you can divide by each variable as they are all non-zero) and substitute equations into each other.

Answer (score 1):

Let put

$$X=\frac{1}{x}$$

$$Y=\frac{1}{y}$$

$$Z=\frac{1}{z}$$

we have

$$X+Y=\frac{1}{a}$$

$$X+Z=\frac{1}{b}$$

$$Y+Z=\frac{1}{c}$$

thus

$$X+Y+Z=\frac{1}{2a}+\frac{1}{2b}+\frac{1}{2c}$$

and

$$X=\frac{1}{2a}+\frac{1}{2b}-\frac{1}{2c}$$

$\implies$

$$x=\frac{2abc   }{bc+ac-ab  }\in \mathbb Q$$